# Resources and Pedastrian Library

Tags: anylogic

I'm modeling the operation of an outpatient clinic and I'm using the pedastrian library because the main purpose of the model is to be able to map the most frequent paths using the density map! The problem is that the density map refers only to the patients that are defined with pedastrian, while the doctors, the nurses and all the professionals, that are defined as resourcePool, do not affect the creation of the density map. The solution I have im[image]plemented is to create a parallel flow in which the resources are created as pedastrian and follow the predefined paths but do not interact with the patient. So I have dual resources, each professional figure is both a resource and a pedastrian! this solution however is unrealistic and very inconvenient to implement. Is there a faster way to have the resources "participate" in the creation of the density map?

Answer (score 0):

It will be more elegant if you use the [Canvas](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/presentation/canvas.html#use-cases) element. This allows both pedestrians and other agents to influence the canvas. Downside is that you need to do the actual "influencing" yourself via code. But the example models show you how to do that.

PS: I believe that the Ped-heatmap element is actually a specific canvas, but I might be wrong